# VBA wrong value of ActiveCell.Top after unplugging monitor

Tags: excel, vba, screen-resolution

Get correct value of `Target.Top` or 'ActiveCell.Top' after unplugging the monitor.

When I run this macro I get the correct value of Target.Top.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   MsgBox Target.Top
End Sub
```

After unplugging monitor, I get different resolution on my laptop, much smaller but returned value remains the same. Program doesn't notice the fact that the resolution changed and returns the same value as before which is wrong. I cannot use the code:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TempCombo").Top=Target.Top
```

to position the combobox because it lands in the wrong place.

Is there a way to reset `Target.Top` (resolution) values?

Comment: Excel distances are measured in [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)), which is 1/72 of an inch. That value should not depend on resolution.

Comment: @GSerg Target.Top values do not change after switching monitors. If it was truly in points per inch, then changing monitors should have no negative effect on positioning objects.

Comment: The unit is twips not points I think, might be a sub/super of point though. And yes they are screen independent so do not change after switching monitors

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same issue with my laptop and a portable monitor connected. If I keep the spreadheet in the laptop monitor the code gets the cells .Top right, if I move the spreadshit in other monitor the .Top is off by about half of the cells height. I solved this by having the macro running with the spreadsheet in my laptop. I know that this sound more like a workaround than an actual so

Answer (score 0):

The same with me.
My macro creates a button on the ActivCell.Top Position.

Set NewButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(ActiveCell.Left + 3, ActiveCell.Top + 3, 60, 20)

After moving the excel to the second screen (Win10 extended destop)
and running the macro again, the button is displaced.
The unwanted offset increases with the length of the worksheet (line number where the
button shall appear).

Since the vertical difference is larger than the horizonal, it seems to
correspond with the delta in the screen resolutions.

The unexpected behaviour disappeares after reboot, but seems to
come up again, several days later.